# С++ Ошибка компиляции. Библиотека d3d11

Tags: c++, c, build, library

При запуске кода командой:

```
g++.exe App/main.cpp App/AppWindow.cpp GameEngine/WindowingSystem/Window.cpp GameEngine/GraphicsEngine/GraphicsEngine.cpp -o main.exe
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\486B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFUVirG.o:GraphicsEngine.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `D3D11CreateDevice'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Почему возникает ошибка?

main, AppWindow, Window Я не привожу т. к. они не влияют на работу (я закомментировал кусочки где используется код GraphicsEngine)

Код **GraphicsEngine.cpp**:

```cpp
#include "GraphicsEngine.h"


GraphicsEngine::GraphicsEngine()
{
}

bool GraphicsEngine::init()
{
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driver_types[]=
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE
    };
    UINT num_driver_types = ARRAYSIZE(driver_types);

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_levels[]=
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0
    };
    UINT num_feature_levels = ARRAYSIZE(feature_levels);

    HRESULT res = 0;
    for (UINT driver_type_index = 0; driver_type_index < num_driver_types;)
    {
        res =D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, driver_types[driver_type_index], NULL, NULL, feature_levels,
            num_feature_levels, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &m_d3d_device, &m_feature_level, &m_imm_context);
        if (SUCCEEDED(res))
            break;
            ++driver_type_index;
    }
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        return false;
    }



    return true;
}


bool GraphicsEngine::release()
{
    m_imm_context->Release();
    m_d3d_device->Release();
    return true;
}

GraphicsEngine::~GraphicsEngine()
{
}


GraphicsEngine * GraphicsEngine::get()
{
    static GraphicsEngine engine;
    return &engine;
}
```

Код **GraphicsEngine.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <d3d11.h>

class SwapChain;
class DeviceContext;

class GraphicsEngine
{
public:
    GraphicsEngine();
    bool init();
    bool release();
    ~GraphicsEngine();
public:
    static GraphicsEngine* get();
    
private:
    ID3D11Device * m_d3d_device;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL m_feature_level;
    ID3D11DeviceContext * m_imm_context;
};
```

Comment: открываете [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-d3d11createdevice) и там внизу написано, какую библиотеку надо линковать для этой функции

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вы не подключили библиотеку с этой функцией через -l?
Тут [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141147/how-do-i-include-a-path-to-libraries-in-g) подключения
И конкретно по этой либе

https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/546427-how-to-linking-directx-library/546427/